# Use Cecil to insert begin/end block around functions

Tags: cil, mono.cecil

this simple code works fine and allows to add a `BeginSample/EndSample` call around each `Update/LateUpdate/FixedUpdate` function. However it doesn't take in consideration early return instructions, for example as result of a condition. Do you know how to write a similar function that take in considerations early returns so that the EndSample call will be executed under every circumstance?

Note that I am not a Cecil expert, I am just learning now. It appears to me that Cecil automatically updates the operations that returns early after calling `InsertBefore` and similar functions. So if a `BR` opcode was previously jumping to a specific instruction address, the address will be updated after the insertions in order to jump to the original instruction. This is OK in most of the cases, but in my case it means that an `if` statement would skip the last inserted operation as the `BR` operation would still point directly to the final `Ret` instruction. Note that `Update`, `LateUpdate` and `FixedUpdate` are all void functions.

```
foreach (var method in type.Methods)
{
    if ((method.Name == "Update" || method.Name == "LateUpdate" || method.Name == "FixedUpdate") &&
        method.HasParameters == false)
    {
        var beginMethod =
            module.ImportReference(typeof (Profiler).GetMethod("BeginSample",
                                                               new[] {typeof (string)}));
        var endMethod =
            module.ImportReference(typeof (Profiler).GetMethod("EndSample",
                                                               BindingFlags.Static |
                                                               BindingFlags.Public));

        Debug.Log(method.Name + " method found in class: " + type.Name);

        var ilProcessor = method.Body.GetILProcessor();

        var first = method.Body.Instructions[0];
        ilProcessor.InsertBefore(first,
                                 Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ldstr,
                                                    type.FullName + "." + method.Name));
        ilProcessor.InsertBefore(first, Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Call, beginMethod));

        var lastRet = method.Body.Instructions[method.Body.Instructions.Count - 1];
        ilProcessor.InsertBefore(lastRet, Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Call, endMethod));

        changed = true;
    }
}
```

as a Bonus, if you can explain to me the difference between `Emit` and `Append` a newly created instruction with the same operand. does Append execute an `Emit` under the hood or does something more?

Comment: Quick comment while knowing nothing about Cecil: if you want to guarantee something always happens regardless of internal control flow, wrapping it in a `try .. finally` block would be the obvious thing to do, rather than hunting down all exit points. Another obvious approach (which combines with that) is to rename the original function and entirely replace it with a wrapper that does `begin() / function() / end()`. Last but not least, you could consider using a profiler rather than apparently reinventing the wheel. Not to say you don't genuinely need your own wheel, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have found the solution, at least apparently it works. I followed the code used to solve a similar problem from here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mono-cecil/nE6JBjvEFCQ/MqV6tgDCB4AJ

I adapted it for my purposes and it seemed to work, although I may find out other issues. This is the complete code:

```
 static bool ProcessAssembly(AssemblyDefinition assembly)
 {
     var changed = false;

     var moduleG = assembly.MainModule;

     var attributeConstructor =
             moduleG.ImportReference(
                 typeof(RamjetProfilerPostProcessedAssemblyAttribute).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
     var attribute = new CustomAttribute(attributeConstructor);
     var ramjet = moduleG.ImportReference(typeof(RamjetProfilerPostProcessedAssemblyAttribute));
     if (assembly.HasCustomAttributes)
     {
         var attributes = assembly.CustomAttributes;
         foreach (var attr in attributes)
         {
             if (attr.AttributeType.FullName == ramjet.FullName)
             {
                 Debug.LogWarning("<color=yellow>Skipping already-patched assembly:</color>  " + assembly.Name);
                 return false;
             }
         }
     }
     assembly.CustomAttributes.Add(attribute);

     foreach (var module in assembly.Modules)
     {
         foreach (var type in module.Types)
         {
             // Skip any classes related to the RamjetProfiler
             if (type.Name.Contains("AssemblyPostProcessor") || type.Name.Contains("RamjetProfiler"))
             {
                 // Todo: use actual type equals, not string matching
                 Debug.Log("Skipping self class : " + type.Name);
                 continue;
             }

             if (type.BaseType != null && type.BaseType.FullName.Contains("UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour"))
             {
                 foreach (var method in type.Methods)
                 {
                     if ((method.Name == "Update" || method.Name == "LateUpdate" || method.Name == "FixedUpdate") &&
                         method.HasParameters == false)
                     {
                         var beginMethod =
                             module.ImportReference(typeof(Profiler).GetMethod("BeginSample",
                                                                                new[] { typeof(string) }));
                         var endMethod =
                             module.ImportReference(typeof(Profiler).GetMethod("EndSample",
                                                                                BindingFlags.Static |
                                                                                BindingFlags.Public));

                         Debug.Log(method.Name + " method found in class: " + type.Name);

                         var ilProcessor = method.Body.GetILProcessor();

                         var first = method.Body.Instructions[0];
                         ilProcessor.InsertBefore(first,
                                                  Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ldstr,
                                                                     type.FullName + "." + method.Name));
                         ilProcessor.InsertBefore(first, Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Call, beginMethod));

                         var lastcall = Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Call, endMethod);

                         FixReturns(method, lastcall);

                         changed = true;
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }

     return changed;
 }

 static void FixReturns(MethodDefinition med, Instruction lastcall)
 {
     MethodBody body = med.Body;

     var instructions = body.Instructions;
     Instruction formallyLastInstruction = instructions[instructions.Count - 1];
     Instruction lastLeaveInstruction = null;

     var lastRet = Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ret);
     instructions.Add(lastcall);
     instructions.Add(lastRet);

     for (var index = 0; index < instructions.Count - 1; index++)
     {
         var instruction = instructions[index];
         if (instruction.OpCode == OpCodes.Ret)
         {
             Instruction leaveInstruction = Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Leave, lastcall);
             if (instruction == formallyLastInstruction)
             {
                 lastLeaveInstruction = leaveInstruction;
             }

             instructions[index] = leaveInstruction;
         }
     }

     FixBranchTargets(lastLeaveInstruction, formallyLastInstruction, body);
 }

 private static void FixBranchTargets(
     Instruction lastLeaveInstruction,
     Instruction formallyLastRetInstruction,
     MethodBody body)
 {
     for (var index = 0; index < body.Instructions.Count - 2; index++)
     {
         var instruction = body.Instructions[index];
         if (instruction.Operand != null && instruction.Operand == formallyLastRetInstruction)
         {
             instruction.Operand = lastLeaveInstruction;
         }
     }
 }
```

basically what it does is to add a `Ret` instuction, but then replace all the previous `Ret` (usually one, why should it be more than one?) with a `Leave` function (don't even know what it means :) ), so that all the previous jumps remain valid. Differently than the original code, I make the `Leave` instruction point to the `EndSample` call before the last `Ret`

Comment: Leave opcodes are just branches (br*) that additionally can be used to jump out of protected regions (try, catch,... - blocks)